# book reference of Ito integral for jump processes

Tags: poisson-process, levy-processes

I would like your help in this: Which **book** would you recommend as a beginners book into **Ito's integral with diffusion and jump processes** (specially the latter). A for dummies sort of book.

I have read Philip Protter 1990 and Bernt Oksendal 2000 but they are quite hard to follow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul Glasserman: Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering.

Salih N. Neftci: An Introduction to the Mathematics of Financial Derivatives